# Adding "Loading"-image on top of ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, listview

I'd like to add a "Loading"-`Image` on the top of my `ListView` while all items are loading, if there are a lot of items being loaded, I still want a nice user experience.

So therefore I want a floating `Image` ( Animated GIF ? ) on top of my `ListView`.

How would one solve this and once you have the floating image or control, how do you make the GIF animated?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's some XAML that I use to create an AJAX-like wait spinner for WPF.  I uses geometry and animation rather than an animated GIF, and you can control the size and rate by tweaking the XAML:

```
<!-- Style for AJAX-like wait spinners -->
<Style x:Key="WaitSpinnerStyle" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                <Viewbox Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}">
                    <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="120" Height="120" >
                        <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" Canvas.Left="20.1696" Canvas.Top="9.76358" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="1.0"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="20.835" Height="20.862" Canvas.Left="2.86816" Canvas.Top="29.9581" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.9"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="19.835" Height="19.862" Canvas.Left="0.00001" Canvas.Top="57.9341" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.8"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="17.835" Height="17.862" Canvas.Left="12.1203" Canvas.Top="83.3163" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.7"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="16.835" Height="16.862" Canvas.Left="36.5459" Canvas.Top="98.1380" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.6"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="14.835" Height="14.862" Canvas.Left="64.6723" Canvas.Top="96.8411" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.5"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="13.835" Height="13.862" Canvas.Left="87.6176" Canvas.Top="81.2783" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.4"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="12.835" Height="12.862" Canvas.Left="98.165"  Canvas.Top="54.4140" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.3"/>
                        <Ellipse Width="11.835" Height="11.862" Canvas.Left="92.9838" Canvas.Top="26.9938" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.2"/>
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinnerRotate" Angle="0" />
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Canvas.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerRotate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                            From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01.3"
                                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Canvas.Triggers>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You use it like this (specify the colour if you want to change it):

```
<Control Style="{StaticResource WaitSpinnerStyle}" Width="35" />
<Control Style="{StaticResource WaitSpinnerStyle}" Width="35" Foreground="Green" />
```

The above XAML would look like this (you have to imagine them spinning!):

[image]

---

To have a layer appear above your ListBox, wrap it in a Grid like this:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- LOADING overlay (for async-load) -->
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="True" 
            Background="#40000000" CornerRadius="4"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Control Style="{StaticResource WaitSpinnerStyle}" Width="35" Foreground="White" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="LOADING..." FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <ListBox />
</Grid>
```

Using a Grid means that the Border will appear on top of the ListBox.  In this case, the layer will appear greyed out, and will steal any mouse actions, effectively disabling the underlying ListBox.

Note that the binding here to `IsLoaded` connects to my view model.  I set it to `false` when I start loading, then again to `true` when the loading completes.  Note that I load my items off the dispatcher thread (on a worker thread) so that the UI updates while I'm doing this work.

Comment: IS the "Binding Path=IsLoading" connected to the ListView, of not how do you set it off?

Comment: @Filip, I've added a clarification to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I am still a little confused on how you "bind" it to your view-model though, could you provide some information about that?

Comment: @Filip, many articles have been written about MVVM that will give you a better overview than I would in a comment here.  Search for 'MVVM' on Google.  Josh Smith has some great articles, and here's one from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: If you don't want to use MVVM, just create a property on the user control.  Note that you will have to make the binding expression have a relative source and search for your user control as an ancestor.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, just created a Binding Property and bound it to the "element" and then said "use my property!" :)
Thanks for the help

Comment: The animation is great, but it consumes 50% CPU. Is there any way to reduce the CPU utilization with this animation ? Thank you.

Comment: @alexandrud, it may be worth experimenting with rendering the visuals to a texture and rotating that somehow. Even just using a RenderTransform to rotate an image may be easier on the CPU.