# how to play animated .gif file in wpf using vb

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

i have a gif with transparent background

I used this code

```
<MediaElement Name="yourMediaElement" Margin="144,83,602,166">
        <MediaElement.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <MediaTimeline Source="videos/stick_figure_podium_speech_group_anim_150_clr_9408.gif"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="yourMediaElement"  
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </MediaElement.Triggers>
    </MediaElement>
```

but it doesn't show the gif when i ran the code.
it only shows in the design window with a black background

is there another way to load a gif image in wpf using vb?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167372/8099567) link answer should be help full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf) or you can download this [CodePlex project](http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/).

From second link:

> A simple library to display animated GIF images in WPF, usable in XAML or in code.
>   It's very easy to use: in XAML, instead of setting the Source property, set the AnimatedSource attached property to the image you want